# Allowing new line characters in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, return, line, newline, feed

I am using live validation on my site  (from livevalidation.com), I have a text area where I need to allow new line / line feed / return characters, but despite my best efforts I am failing miserably. I have tried \n \r \v \s\S each with \ escape and without.

This is my code without the use of the above chars:

```
my_notes.add( Validate.Format, { pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9&#192;&#193;&#194;&#195;&#196;&#197;&#198;&#199;&#200;&#201;&#202;&#203;&#204;&#205;&#206;&#207;&#208;&#209;&#210;&#211;&#212;&#213;&#214;&#216;&#217;&#218;&#219;&#220;&#221;&#223;&#224;&#225;&#226;&#227;&#228;&#229;&#230;&#231;&#232;&#233;&#234;&#235;&#236;&#237;&#238;&#239;&#241;&#242;&#243;&#244;&#245;&#246;&#248;&#249;&#250;&#251;&#252;&#253;&#255;\.\,\-\/\']+[a-zA-Z0-9&#192;&#193;&#194;&#195;&#196;&#197;&#198;&#199;&#200;&#201;&#202;&#203;&#204;&#205;&#206;&#207;&#208;&#209;&#210;&#211;&#212;&#213;&#214;&#216;&#217;&#218;&#219;&#220;&#221;&#223;&#224;&#225;&#226;&#227;&#228;&#229;&#230;&#231;&#232;&#233;&#234;&#235;&#236;&#237;&#238;&#239;&#241;&#242;&#243;&#244;&#245;&#246;&#248;&#249;&#250;&#251;&#252;&#253;&#255;\.\,\-\/\' ]+$/i } );
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow; that's quite a regex. What is it meant to do?

Comment: You can't use HTML entities inside your character class.  Instead of #192; use \xc0.  The accented character À will work too.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, will see about getting it adjusted. It is supposed to allow input special chars without being too retentive. So people can enter names with accents etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /m modifier allows the pattern to match across multiple lines, where you have /i at the end of your pattern try /mi instead

Comment: This is not actually what `m` does. `m` makes `^` and `$` match line beginnings and endings respectively. "Matching across multiple" lines is possible with or without `m` provided you have something that matches line breaks (like `\s`). So what the pattern now does is simply validate that one of the lines has the correct format (the other lines can contain arbitrary characters). I think David Gorsline has found the real issue in the comment on the question.